# "would ensure Iranˈs nuclear program will be exclusively peaceful"

Tags: word-meaning

> The goal for these negotiations is to reach a mutually-agreed long-term comprehensive solution that **would** ensure Iranˈs nuclear program will be exclusively peaceful

what does "would" imply here? why not "will"?

Comment: Such a solution doesn't yet exist; _if_ it existed, it _would_ ensure [the desired result]. (By the way, I assume you mean _in the context below_?

Comment: Strictly speaking, conditional / hypothetical ***would ensure*** should be reflected by ***would be exclusively peaceful***, but native speakers don't like to repeat "complicated" verb forms any more than they have to. Just one instance of ***would*** is enough to convey the fact that this goal is only hypothetical, and ***may not be achieved***.